# How to fix ANDI css content alert

Tags: css, accessibility, pseudo-element, andi

I'm running the Accessibility Name & Description Inspector tool against my web page and it is reporting this hidden content CSS alert:

> CSS Content Alerts: (1)
> Content has been injected using CSS pseudo-elements ::before or ::after.

This is the part of the HTML that is causing the error:

```
<i _ngcontent-nbn-c320="" role="img" class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off hANDI508- 
hasHiddenCssContent" title="alerts sounding" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
```

Specifically, this is the CSS class that is causing it:

```
glyphicon-volume-off:before{content:"\e036"}
```

It doesn't like the `content:"\e036"`.

It wants me to not have it, but if I do, my glyphicon won't show on the page.

What can I do so it doesn't report it? Is there a way?

Comment: If you **don't** want the :before/:after element included in the accessible name, then it needs to be specified on an element with `aria-hidden="true"`. If you **do** want the :before/:after element included in the accessible name, then you don't have to do anything, other than making sure the `content` is a pronounceable character. As mentioned in my comment on @tylerh's answer, the `content` will be automatically included as part of the accessible name. It's wrong for a tool to flag that in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the warning, because content in pseudo-elements is an [inherent accessibility failure](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F87.html):

> The CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements specify the location of content before and after an element's document tree content. The `content` property, in conjunction with these pseudo-elements, specifies what is inserted. For users who need to customize or turn off style information in order to view content according to their needs, assistive technologies may not be able to access the information that is inserted using CSS. Therefore, it is a failure to use these properties to insert non-decorative content.

You can, however, *ignore* the warning if the content is decorative, or if you include the substance of the inserted content elsewhere in a location that is accessible via a screen reader or other assistive technology. You can do that via `title` or `aria-label` attributes in the element, or depending on the situation, use the `.sr-only` class on a descriptive text element if you're using Bootstrap.

Keep in mind ANDI states that an alert is not necessarily a problem:

> It's up to a human to evaluate ANDI's results and make the final decision on whether or not there is an accessibility issue.

See ANDI's guidance on how to handle this from [their Alerts documentation](https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/andi/help/alerts.html):

> #### Why is this an accessibility concern?
>
> Depending on the browser being used, Content injected using this technique may not recognized by screen readers, therefore, the text may not be communicated to individuals using assistive technologies. Specifically, in Internet Explorer screen readers will not detect recognize CSS pseudo-element content.

> #### What should be done?
>
> If the content is meaningful or important, it should be made apparent to a blind individual using a screen reader.
>
> If the meaning of the injected content is available elsewhere on the page, no change is needed. Otherwise, remediation options are as follows:
>
> - Abandon the CSS content injection technique and place text directly on the screen or use inline images.
> - Properly [name and describe](https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/andi/help/developerguide.html#NamingAndDescribing) elements with which the injected css content associates.

Comment: The failure condition you mentioned is not a normative document. These failures (and "Sufficient Techniques") mentioned in the "understanding" section of each guideline are just advice and whether you follow them or fail them are not real failures. The [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) specifically says that :before and :after elements are included in the accessible name (step 2F). If a user turns off stylesheets, there isn't a requirement that the page has to be accessible. Similar to if the user turns of javascript, the page doesn't have to be accessible

Comment: @slugolicious Indeed, I don't think I mention anywhere that the documents are normative or that OP _must_ do any particular action, though they _should_ consider following them to comply with A11Y best practices (and if they are using ANDI, there's a chance their target audience is a government agency or in a state that _does_ require certain A11Y 'scores'). A11Y standards are sometimes separate from W3C or WHATWG spec requirements, which are in general more about what browsers must do rather than what authors must do.